# Swagger for jersey endpoint with form url encoded

Tags: java, swagger, jersey-2.0

I have a DropWizard project with jersey 2.17, with a simple form submission endpoint:

```
@Path("forms/{form_id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@ApiOperation(value = "Submit a form", response = SubmittedForm.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Valid request - form submitted", response = SubmittedForm.class)
})
public Response submitForm(@PathParam("form_id") String formId, MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters) {
    ...
}
```

I'm using Swagger (swagger-jersey2-jaxrs 1.5.4) to document my API. However, for this endpoint there is no documentation generated for form parameters. If I change `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` to `MultivaluedStringMap` then there is doc generated but it is recognised as a body parameter. 
I cannot use `@PathParam` for the form parameters, as this endpoint will support multiple form definitions, so keys are not known.

Is there any way to document form submission endpoint (with url-encoded params) properly using Swagger?

Comment: No, I mean [`javax.ws.rs.core.Form`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Form.html). You can have this as a parameter for url-endcoded form data

Comment: Actually maybe not. I'm not really sure how it would work.

Comment: Yeaa, it doesn't seem to work for me either - no change in swagger + it broke my tests ;)

Comment: Do you have a resolution now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An arbitrary map is not permitted in the swagger specification, and therefore it won't be detected when scanning the operation.  Per [the spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameter-object), only *serializable* types are supported for Form params.

Comment: thank you for the input, but it doesn't really answer my question on how to achieve what I need, and that is: using Swagger document form submission endpoint with not known param names. Can you maybe provide some kind of example of how to do it? Or are you stating that this is not possible?

Comment: I'm saying that inside the specification, it is not allowed, and therefore not supported in the tools.  You can always hack the front/back ends to support it, or contribute your feedback to the spec so it's supported in the next version

Comment: Ok, I created a class that implements `Serializable`, and that has one field(`String`), with getters and setters. It's used instead of the `MultivaluedMap` from the example above. I've added provider to `Dropwizard`, so it recognises my class as acceptable for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Still, this param is recognised by `Swagger` as `body` param and not `formData`. What should I do for this param to be recognised as `formData`?

Comment: Take a look at how to annotate the `formData` types:  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/master/java/java-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/sample/resource/PetResource.java#L165

Comment: Kind of hoped that `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` would do the trick for not annotated param. Thanks